# Checkbox: remove the square on focus

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, focus

How can I remove the small square arround the radio button that gets displayed when the input gets focused?

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I don't know what the square is actually called and couldn't find what I'm looking for.

I tried `autocomplete="off"` on the input. I played arround with jQuery's `preventDefault` but without success.

Update:
Thanks for your responses. If anyone comes accross this question, here is the effect of `appearance` attached (upper pic without appearance, the one below is with appearance) with Firefox:

[image]

*Just in case someone comes to the same problem.*

**Update** with Chrome / Safari, `appearance` **removes** the input

> `-webkit-appearance: none;` would make the radio buttons disappear in
>   Chrome and Safari. check jsfiddle.net/8uY6H (with Chrome)

– noted by JFK 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS since it is an outline:

```
input[type="radio"]:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `outline:0` property for the radio button on focus

```
input[type="radio"]:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: `outline:0` is not valid CSS

Comment: `0` doesn't work with most recent Firefox, `none` did work. However, I upvoted both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set:

```
outline:none;
```

On the `:focus` state of the CSS class relating to the checkbox, or directly e.g.

```
input[type="radio"]:focus{
    outline:none;
}
```

**[The crucial part is setting `outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)**

> The CSS outline property is a shorthand property for setting one or
>   more of the individual outline properties outline-style, outline-width
>   and outline-color in a single rule. In most cases the use of this
>   shortcut is preferable and more convenient.

**[However, also setting `appearance` may help cross platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)** where different browsers render checkbox elements differently.

As noted in the comments below though, this will cause the checkbox to not display in some circumstances- so you would need to produce a pure CSS solution.

> The -moz-appearance CSS property is used in Gecko (Firefox) to display
>   an element using a platform-native styling based on the operating
>   system's theme.
>
> This property is frequently used in XUL stylesheets to design custom
>   widgets with platform-appropriate styling. It is also used in the XBL
>   implementations of the widgets that ship with the Mozilla platform.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of `appearance`

Comment: - 1 : `-webkit-appearance: none;` would make the radio buttons disappear in Chrome and Safari. check http://jsfiddle.net/8uY6H/ (with Chrome)

Comment: I cannot down-vote you once more cause you just replicated james and donjuwe answers ;)

Comment: @jfk - If its any consolation, James noted the wrong setting of `outline`, donjuwe answered afterward

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
input[type="radio"] {
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9xqxt/)</kbd>

Comment: Several solutions. Is the combination of 0 and none the *best* ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany : `outline` is a shorthand property that combines two or more individual `outline` properties. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline